# toString() a generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics

How can I print the type of a generic java type?

Reflection? Any tricks?

```
public class Foo<K> {

    private K element;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Type: " + K;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`element.getClass().getSimpleName()` will probably do what you are expecting.

Comment: Would K.class.getSimpleName() also do the trick? It's over 10 years since I java'd so I missed generics. I might be wrong.

Comment: But if the element variable is not initialised, is there any other way of getting the type without getting a null pointer exception?

Comment: K.class will not work (probably not even compile). And yes, you need to null-check. And no, there is no other way because of type erasure (no runtime information about K unless you store it yourself).

Comment: @davidrobles hmm. Not sure, actually

Answer (score 6):

Because of [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure), you can't know that what was the type parameter when the class was constructed. But you can use `element.getClass()` to get the runtime type of the element (which is probably a subclass of the type parameter, although it's not guaranteed - there could have been an unchecked cast).

However, there are some tricks that enable access to the type parameters. There are some tricks that [Guice can do](http://publicobject.com/2008/11/guice-punches-erasure-in-face.html). Also if you create a subclass of Foo, like this: `Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>(){};` (notice the `{}` which makes it an anonymous subclass of Foo), then it's possible to get access to the type parameter with `ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) foo.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` and then calling the methods of [ParameterizedType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html). This is the feature of Java's reflection API that also Guice takes advantage of.